# Comparing values of a stored procedure with the latest entered row and some fixed row

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, compare

I created a table with two columns which has logtime values,such as:

> CREATE TABLE REF_LOGTIME
>   (
>   LOGTIME1 datetime NOT NULL,
>   LOGTIME2 datetime NOT NULL
>   )
>
> INSERT INTO REF_LOGTIME(LOGTIME1,LOGTIME2) VALUES ('2014-09-1 07:09:00.000','2014-10-10 07:10:00.000')

I have a stored procedure which returns logtime,beam_current,st1_vs1_bag1_rb....and many more.
I want to compare the latest entered row into the stored procedure with the rows which are between the LOGTIME1 and LOGTIME2 and have to retrieve only those rows where the beam_current is 10mA,20mA,30mA....100mA and calculate the difference between various BAG VALUES  i.e st1_vs1_bag1_rb,st1_vs1_bag2_rb.. only where beam_current is 10mA,20mA...
I'm using Sql Server 2102.

Comment: What do you mean `latest entered row into the stored procedure`?

Comment: Are there any inputs to the stored proc based on which the rows are returned or does it return only one row at a time?

Comment: latest entered row means that the new row which is being inserted. It is a live database,rows are inserted at per second according to the operation.No stored procedure does not return one row at a time,but returns row on the basis of time entered as parameters into the query.

Comment: `I want to compare the latest entered row into the stored procedure with the rows which are between the LOGTIME1 and LOGTIME2` - You want to compare which two tables? I am only guessing you want to compare the latest row which entered the first table against `REF_LOGTIME`(which is the second table) and get some results based on some conditions. How do determine the latest row? Is there a timestamp or identity column?

Comment: yes,Logtime is the identity column.It stores the time period .

Comment: What is the name of the table which has all these columns? Where does the stored proc come into the picture? Do you want to wrap this logic inside this stored proc of yours?

Comment: Is my understanding correct? - `You want to compare the latest row which entered the first table against REF_LOGTIME(which is the second table) and get some results based on some conditions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to compare the last inserted row in a table with this table `REF_LOGTIME` AND get values based on the given condition. You have not provided enough details, so I would assume the table which you are interested in getting values out of is say `TableOfValues`. The below query gives you what I understand you need. Please check and let me know if it works. You can wrap it up in the stored proc if you need to.

```
SELECT A.LogTime, A.Beam_Current, B.LOGTIME1, B.LOGTIME2
CASE WHEN  (A.Beam_Current / 10) IN (1, 2) 
THEN (A.st1_vs1_bag1_rb - A.st1_vs1_bag2_rb) ELSE NULL END AS DIFF_BAG_VALUES --To check if beam_current is 10mA,20mA
 FROM 
      (
        SELECT TOP 1 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LogTime) Row_Num,  
        logtime,beam_current,st1_vs1_bag1_rb, st1_vs1_bag2_rb
        FROM [TableOfValues] ORDER BY 1 DESC   --To get the latest entered row 
      )A JOIN REF_LOGTIME B ON A.LOGTIME BETWEEN B.LOGTIME1 AND B.LOGTIME2
    AND B.Beam_Current % 10 = 0 -- To check if beam_current is 10mA,20mA,30mA....100mA
```